# How rendering handling concurrency in razor page from API response?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I have defined a put method with try catch for handling concurrency errors.

I also define Timestamp attibute in class model.

1. put method

   ```
   [HttpPut]

   public async Task<IActionResult> Put(ProjetModel projetModel)
   {
       _context.Entry(projetModel).State = EntityState.Modified;

       try
        {
          await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
         {
           //throw;
          var exceptionEntry = ex.Entries.Single();
          var clientValues = (ProjetModel)exceptionEntry.Entity;
          var databaseEntry = exceptionEntry.GetDatabaseValues();
          var dbValues = (ProjetModel)databaseEntry.ToObject();
          await SetDbErrorMessage(dbValues, clientValues);

          projetModel.ConcurrencyToken = (byte[])dbValues.ConcurrencyToken;
          ModelState.Remove($"{nameof(projetModel)}.{nameof(projetModel.ConcurrencyToken)}");

          return BadRequest(ModelState);
       }
       return NoContent();
   }
   private async Task SetDbErrorMessage(ProjetModel dbValues,
                                  ProjetModel clientValues)
   {

       if (dbValues.Title != clientValues.Title)
       {
           ModelState.AddModelError("ProjetModel.Title",
               $"Current value: {dbValues.Title}");
       }
       if (dbValues.Type != clientValues.Type)
       {
           ModelState.AddModelError("ProjetModel.Type",
               $"Current value: {dbValues.Type:c}");
       }
       if (dbValues.DateProjet != clientValues.DateProjet)
       {
           ModelState.AddModelError("ProjetModel.DateProjet",
               $"Current value: {dbValues.DateProjet:d}");
       }
       if (dbValues.Statut != clientValues.Statut)
       {
           ModelState.AddModelError("ProjetModel.Statut",
               $"Current value: {dbValues.Statut:d}");
       }
       ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
                                  "The record you attempted to edit "
                                + "was modified by another user after you. The "
                                + "edit operation was canceled and the current values in the database "
                                + "have been displayed. If you still want to edit this record, click "
                                + "the Save button again.");
   }
   ```

When I run the app and dev tool with two browsers page and modify two item in each pages :
_First page I can code status 200 OK
_Second page I can see status 400 bad request.
I can see in dev tool network/answer from api :
[image]

=> this means that API when I invoke the put method all things works well.

Right now, I can't display the api response when I invoke the put method.

Could someone help me display the put method response in the razor page?

For information, I'm not in the case of an EditForm

I'd really appreciate your help, I'm really stuck on this point. Thank you very much in advance

You will find below that I try to do

```
async Task OnUpdateRow(ProjetModel newRow)
{
    var response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/projetbe", newRow);             

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // //IT'S HERE THAT I DON'T KNOW I CAN DO??
        // Project updated successfully
        // Handle success logic if needed
      
            
    }
    else
    {
        var errorResponse = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
        // Handle error response and display error messages to the user
        foreach (var errors in errorResponse.Values)
        {
            foreach (var error in errors)
            {
                 //IT'S HERE THAT I DON'T KNOW I CAN DO??
                // Display error messages to the user
                // You can use RadzenNotification or any other UI component for displaying errors
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this really a `Bad Request`?  I don't believe in sticking with REST standards in my own APIs.  I apply CQS principles to data pipeline operations and return informative result objects.  Everything's a `Post`.  The request was a success, the result wasn't.

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis, handling concurrency errors with a Timestamp attribute in Blazor WebAssembly involves detecting when a record has been modified by another user since it was loaded, and then rendering an error message to the user. I try do it in blazor!! I've defined the put method according to the microsoft link : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio. Now my I want to rendering the error message in razor page!